# Springfox Swagger - Display ChronoUnit enum values using Indices

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

UPDATE:

As noted below, a colleague was able to answer my question. I will leave it up here in case it is helpful to anyone else.

The answer:

> All that was necessary was to add the @ApiModelProperty annotation to
> the ChronoUnit field, like the following:

```
@ApiModelProperty(dataType = "string", allowableValues = "NANOS, MICROS, MILLIS, SECONDS, MINUTES, HOURS, HALF_DAYS, DAYS, WEEKS, MONTHS, YEARS, DECADES, CENTURIES, MILLENNIA,ERAS, FOREVER") 
private ChronoUnit durationType;
```

> It was not even necessary to add @ApiModel annotation to the class it
> exists in, as everything else in the class sticks to the defaults.

=====================================

In my team's project, we have an entity with a java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit field. In the class, it is defined like this:

```
    @NotNull
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name="duration_type", nullable = false)
    @JsonView({Views.RequestDetailView.class})
    private ChronoUnit durationType;
```

This enumerated type has indices (NANOS, SECONDS, HOURS, etc), as well as key-value pairs associated with these indices, such as

```
    NANOS("Nanos", Duration.ofNanos(1)),
```

Our springfox-generated Swagger prints the name, rather than the index. In other words, it prints:

```
"durationType":{"type":"string","enum":["Nanos","Micros","Millis","Seconds","Minutes","Hours","HalfDays","Days","Weeks","Months","Years","Decades","Centuries","Millennia","Eras","Forever"]}
```

instead of

```
"durationType":{"type":"string","enum":["NANOS","MICROS","MILLIS","SECONDS","MINUTES","HOURS","HALF_DAYS","DAYS","WEEKS","MONTHS","YEARS","DECADES","CENTURIES","MILLENNIA","ERAS","FOREVER"]}
```

This would not matter, except that automated testing tools pick up on these names, send one in the request, and the request fails because it does not match the index.

This is what the endpoint it tests against looks like:

```
    @ApiResponses(value = ....)
    @ApiOperation(value = "Update Container", notes = "Update Container")
    @PostMapping(value = "/{id}", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity updateContainer(@PathVariable("id") id, @RequestBody final Request request){
....
}
```

The code inside the method doesn't matter, because the request will not reach it, instead bouncing off with a 400 response.

At this point, I do need to clarify that we absolutely have identified the problem to be with the ChronoUnit field- if we use the index (ie, SECONDS, HOURS, etc) or remove the field from our request, we receive a valid response.

My question is, how do we get springfox to print the INDEX instead of the "name" in the Swagger document, or can we make it so that our application recognizes the "name" of the enumerated type ChronoUnit?

As a note, our springfox Docket is defined like the following:

```
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .apiInfo(apiInfoSwagger2())
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("....controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())  
                .build()
                .protocols(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("https")))
                .securitySchemes(getSecuritySchemes())
                .securityContexts(getSecurityContexts())
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(true)
        ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided by a colleague, so I will put it up here. All that was necessary was to add the @ApiModelProperty annotation to the ChronoUnit field, like the following:

```
@ApiModelProperty(dataType = "string", allowableValues = "NANOS, MICROS, MILLIS, SECONDS, MINUTES, HOURS, HALF_DAYS, DAYS, WEEKS, MONTHS, YEARS, DECADES, CENTURIES, MILLENNIA,ERAS, FOREVER") 
private ChronoUnit durationType;
```

It was not even necessary to add @ApiModel annotation to the class it exists in, as everything else in the class sticks to the defaults.